# matplotlib.pyplot.fill pdf export is different to figure in IDE

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, vector-graphics

i wrote a script for plotting with python3. I used the `fill` command for filling squares:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.fill(x,y,c)
```

In the figure of my IDE everything is fine. But the exported pdf has to big areas of the squares. See picture link below, i think it is a problem of the huge range of different sizes of the squares. I export the pdf via the GUI of the figure. I tested all other possible vector-graphics formats via the GUI with the same result. I want to have a vector-graphic for print. Thanks.

[image: IDE_figure_and_pdf]

edit: some example code to test

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

#Input
n=7

#Calc
for i in range(1, n+1):
    mycolor=cm.viridis(255//(n)*(i))
    k=1/(4**i)
    plt.fill([0,k,k,0,0],([0,0,k,k,0]),color=mycolor[0:3],alpha=1) 
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('file.pdf', format='pdf')
```

Comment: Why are there 3 figures in your image you shared? Try the following two lines: `plt.tight_layout()`and then `plt.savefig('file.eps', format='eps')`

Comment: Can you reproduce this with less complicated conglomerates (e.g. one 3 squares of different size) and share the code that allows to obtain that result? (see [mcve])

Comment: @Bazingaa In the Middle is the whole plot, which i want to export. Picturesections of IDE and PDF are below. The two commands doesn't improve the export result.

Comment: In general `savefig` should come *before* `show`. Not sure in how far this could create the reported problem though. [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5753M.png) i get, which looks the same to me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for testing. Yes in your view you posted the plots look quite the same. If you zoom in to the smallest (yellow) square, i can see in my two plots a difference.